# Conteo de comprobantes mostrando todos los meses

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un conteo de comprobantes cual ya esta realizado y me bota por fecha, ahora el problema que quiero que se muestren todos los meses del año, podrían ayudarme en esta función que mi cabeza esta volando. 
que me aconsejan amigos

ejemplo: nombre | mov | enero | febrero | marzo |..... | Total

[image: imagen de muestra de codigos]

```
select sucursal.nombre,venta.ejercicio,venta.mov, count(*) [Enero] from 
venta (nolock)
left outer join sucursal (nolock) on venta.sucursal = sucursal.sucursal
left outer join movtipo (nolock) on venta.mov = movtipo.mov and 
movtipo.modulo = 'vtas' and 
movtipo.clave in 
('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
where venta.ejercicio = '2018'and
  venta.periodo = '1' and
  venta.mov not like 'E-%' and
  movtipo.clave in 
('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
group by sucursal.nombre,venta.ejercicio,venta.mov
```

Comment: vos queres los meses en horizontal? como nombre de columna?

Comment: que siga el recorrido enero | febrero | marzo | ...|total  y si ay otro forma estaría bien también.

Comment: pero como columnas? porque no se entiende bien que esperas de salida...

Comment: a si es amigo, solo quiero que me muetra una cantidad por cada mes como se muestra

Comment: Busca información sobre tablas pivot, tal vez eso te ayude con tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma de hacer esa agrupación por mes es lo siguiente:

```
select sucursal.nombre,venta.ejercicio,venta.mov, venta.periodo AS mes,  
count(venta.periodo) total_mes from 
venta (nolock)
left outer join sucursal (nolock) on venta.sucursal = sucursal.sucursal
left outer join movtipo (nolock) on venta.mov = movtipo.mov and 
movtipo.modulo = 'vtas' and 
movtipo.clave in 
('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
where venta.ejercicio = '2018'and
   venta.mov not like 'E-%' and
   movtipo.clave in 
     ('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
group by sucursal.nombre,venta.ejercicio,venta.mov,venta.periodo
```

En el fondo, esto no te generará una columna por cada mes, pero te agregará para cada registro el mes y el número de ventas asociados.
Ya con eso tu puedes iterar para hacer listados en HTML o en la tecnología que ocupes como frontend.

Para hacerlo como tu quieres, si bien se puede, no es muy optimo ya que tendrías que hacer un select para cada mes (Consultas anidadas por si lo quieres investigar).

Prueba eso y dime como te funciona, ya que al no conocer la estructura completa de tu tabla podría haber algún error

Espero aportar

Comment: Encontré mi propia ayuda, espero entiendan y gracias por tu atención también amigo

Answer (score 0):

```
with comprobante (Sucursal, Tipo_de_comprobante, Año, Mes, Total) as
(select sucursal.nombre, venta.mov, venta.ejercicio, venta.periodo, count(venta.mov) 
Total from venta (nolock)
left outer join sucursal (nolock) on venta.sucursal = sucursal.sucursal
left outer join movtipo (nolock) on venta.mov = movtipo.mov and movtipo.modulo = 
'vtas' and 
movtipo.clave in ('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
where venta.ejercicio = '2018'and
  venta.mov not like 'E-%' and
  movtipo.clave in 
 ('vtas.fb','vtas.f','vtas.fc','vtas.fg','vtas.d','vtas.dc','vtas.b')
group by sucursal.nombre, venta.mov, venta.ejercicio, venta.periodo )
select * from comprobante 
pivot (sum(Total) for Mes in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
[11], [12])) PVT
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta?

Comment: a si es amigo, ya con la consulta armada encierro y agrego un with luego lo termino con un pivot

Comment: entonces debes explicarla, por que solo responder con código se considera de baja calidad